# Different instance of solr for staging and production

Tags: solr

Is it possible to have different instance of Solr  - one pointing to the staging website while other pointing to production website while the CMS sytem is common to both Solr instance. 
I am not checking about high availability or scaling or solr but want to have two separate solr instance so that staging envrironment can be completely separate from production CD environment in DMZ zone with no linking to internal environments like staging.

Comment: I'm confused about your question. You say you want different SOLR instance "while the CMS sytem is common to both Solr instance". Not sure what you mean there. Each instance will point to SOLR using the connection string provided in its config file.

Comment: that is the reason i want to know if it is possible to have two connectionstring in the single CMS instance so that i can use separate solr server for staging and production cd website. Or if there is any other best practise.

Comment: But you say "single CMS instance" and then mention 2 environments (staging and prod),  which I'd consider as 2 CMS instances.

Comment: Is the Sitecore instance a single instance or does the Production CD has its own set of configuration and staging has its own?

Comment: @josedbaez - the two instance I am talking about are the CD server which are actually hosting the public facing website.Single CMS publish content to  the web database of both CD i.e. staging and production website. I am separating out the CMS and CD so the CMS is a single instance while CD are two instance one for staging website while other for production website. The challenge is from the single CMS where I cannot  point to two solr services,

Comment: So you have one Sitecore CA instance with two publication targets (Prod and Staging) and you want the Staging and Prod sites to have different Solr urls? I’m guessing you CD servers are separate and there are separate servers for the Prod and Staging CD sites?

Comment: @AdamSeabridge- yes you are right, we have separate cd for prod and staging

Comment: @user1380223 since you have different instance for prod and staging, you can update the Solr url for each of them

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know one Sitecore CM instance can only index to one SOLR instance. If you want it to index to two different SOLR instances that you want to use, then you need to find a way to replicate between those two SOLR instance. You point your CM to SOLR instance A, then you replicate that to SOLR instance B.